# How to Increase the number of characters in EXCEL 2013 cells?

Tags: excel

How to Increase the number of characters in Excel 2013 cell values? Because I have 5 Lack length of the characters. I tried to Insert the values to single row or cell, but that time cell was split and insert the values into another row. How to handle and If there is any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Excel allows you to enter `32,767` maximum characters in a CELL**. Nothing you can do about that.

HOWEVER in some cases you will see `#####` signs on your cell. This suggests that simply the format is incorrect and by changing it to `GENERAL` you may as well be able to add additional characters.

**Here you can learn more on limits in Excel:**

https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-16c69c74-3d6a-4aaf-ba35-e6eb276e8eaa

Comment: Can you increase the character limit by merging cells?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent were you able to figure out if the character limit stays same for merged cells?